# Row spacing in align environment

Tags: align, amsmath, line-spacing

In the folling example there is not enough space to list all sets begind the "forall" in one row. Moving a part to the next row creates an unnecessary space between the rows (see picture). How to make the row "shift upwards"?

```
\begin{align*}
 & 1\geq\sum\limits _{\substack{asdfaf,\\
asfasf,\\
asfadf
}
}x_{j} &  & \forall j\in A\cup B\\
 &  &  & \cup C\cup D
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I tried to use an array but it has a margin that ruins the alignment with everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool: use a nested `aligned`, instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
1\geq\sum_{\substack{asdfaf,\\
asfasf,\\
asfadf
}
}x_{j}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
\forall j &\in A\cup B\\
          &\cup C\cup D
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]